# Unicode Character Concatenation ANd return in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to Concatenate two unicode characters by using CHrw and returns it back to a variable as char in vb.net, Here i have added two unicode characters and return it back to a NewValue char variable, but when i type J on textbox, Only one character is returning

```
Function SindhiInput(MyInputBox As TextBox, OldValue As KeyPressEventArgs) As Char        

    Dim CursorPosition As Integer = MyInputBox.SelectionStart
    Dim NewValue As Char = ""

    Select Case OldValue.KeyChar

        Case "J"
            NewValue = ChrW(&H62C) + ChrW(&H6BE)

            CursorPosition += 1

    End Select
    MyInputBox.SelectionStart = CursorPosition

    Return NewValue

End Function
```

It Only returns the first character " Arabic Ghe"

How can I return both of these concatenated characters not just one ?? Please Help

Comment: A `Char` type can only hold one character. You'll need to use a `String` type to hold more than one.

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more specific, Char is limited to 2 bytes but your character seems to be 4 bytes

```
    Dim c As Char = "جھ"    ' this gives compilation warning "Implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Char'."
    Dim c As Char = "جھ"c   ' this gives compilation error "Character constant must contain exactly one character."
    Dim s As String = "جھ"  ' this is ok
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried on variable as string but it doesnot work. I think the problem is may be here.. I have used Keypress event and keychar, so it cant take two characters.. how do i resolve this problem ?

```
        Private Sub RTFInputBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RTFInputBox.KeyPress

        If SindhiToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then
        e.KeyChar = SindhiInput(RTFInputBox, e)


    ElseIf UrduToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then
        'e.KeyChar = UrduiInput(e)
    ElseIf ArabicToolStripMenuItem.Checked Then
        'e.KeyChar = ArabicInput(e)
    End If
End Sub
```